# Need to duplicate a row an its related data in other tables. Revision a row

Tags: sql, t-sql

My company has a database with Project related data.  At times, they would like to Revise a project, keeping the old version and copying it so they can work on a copied version.  The project table has a revision field that defaults to 0 and should increment by one when they click a revise button on the front-end website.  The hierarchy would look like:

```
Project(ProjectID)
    Project_Details:  (ID) | (ProjectID)
    Activities:  (ID)  |  (ProjectID)
        Activity_Details:  (ID)  |  (ActivitiesID)
```

ProjectID will link all my tables together.  I Have an Activities table that will contain activities for a project.  So one to many.  The Activities table will link all of its table by ActivityID.

What i Have so far just to test out:

```
INSERT INTO Project SELECT projectnumber, MAX(Revision)+1 FROM Project Where projectnumber = '23.444.555'
SELECT @@IDENTITY
INSERT INTO ProjectDatails SELECT @@IDENTITY, Rate, Department FROM ProjectDatails where projectid = @projectid 

INSERT INTO Activities SELECT @@IDENTITY, Area_No, Completed_Date FROM Activities where projectid = @projectid
```

This is where i am not sure what to do from here.  I need to copy all my rows from an Activity_Details table that relate to my Activities table by activityid.  However, there are multiple rows in my Activities table with the same ProjectID.
So it looks something like a foreach row in Activities with ProjectID = @projectid, get the activityid in that row, copy all rows in Activity_Details with that activityid.

How do I accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a loop. What you need is a mapping between the 'old' and 'new' activity records and use that mapping to create the Activity_details with the correct ActivityID.

If you can add another field on Activities, which will store the *last* ActivityID that record was copied from, you can use that in the join to insert into activities details:

```
INSERT INTO Activities (ProjectID, Area_No, Completed_Date, Last_ActivityID) 
SELECT @newprojectid, Area_No, Completed_Date, ActivityID FROM Activities where projectid = @projectid

INSERT INTO Activity_Details (ActivityID, Details) 
SELECT Activities.ActivityID, Details FROM Activity_Details
    INNER JOIN Activities ON Activity_Details.ActivityID = Activities.Last_ActivityID 
where Activities.projectid = @newprojectid
```

If you cannot (or don't want to) add that field, you will have to rely on a `MERGE` statement to get the get the mapping. Quite a bit trickier, but still doable. Probably best left to a different answer, if desired.

Comment: 2 things are going wrong.  Also, i am working with your first solution.  If, on the initial creation of the project activity, i don't fill in the Activity.Last_ActivityID, my Activity_Details does not get copied.  If, on the initial creation of the project activity, i DO fill in the Activity.Last_ActivityID with the same id from what is auto-generated for Activity.ID, it duplicates the Activity_Detail records.  So one activity will now show the same Activity_Detail twice.

Comment: I realised a typo which could be part the reason. I've changed the last line in the first solution to be `where Activities.projectid = @newprojectid`. When selecting Activites, it's meant to be "join on the *new* records, selecting the *old* activity ID". If you are getting duplicates it means `Last_ActivityID` is also being duplicated (most likely). If you update the question with your version of the SQL it can be analyzed further.